# How to add spaces in between numbers contained inside a string?

Tags: java, android

I have string as `"DOC_87654321 -ABC76543"`. What I want is add spaces in between numbers. The result should be `"DOC_8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1-ABC7 6 5 4 3"`. How can it possible?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You could use string builder and append space after numeric value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
String str = "DOC_87654321 -ABC76543";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        sb.append(c + " ");
    } else {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
Log.e("DATA",sb.toString());
```

Comment: This will not output anything.

Comment: @Lokesh didn't get u

Comment: It's okay it's fine now

Comment: OP was asking for space *between* numbers, not *after*. But I think this can be left as an exercise.

Comment: @Henry agree with u i gave him just hint

Comment: Nilu its works.Thanks

Comment: @Noufal happy to help you my friend

Comment: does this not add space after number 1 in the input string while op asked for space between numbers

Comment: @Raghunandan sir i have just give him hint

Comment: @Noufal In case if you don't wanna use the `Character.isDigit` function use this `if(str.charAt(i) >= 48 && str.charAt(i) <=57)`

Comment: @Lokesh or even better `if(str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9')`

Comment: @Henry what ever you say sir , you are the boss !! (y) :) +1 I was just encouraging him not to use all the Java APIs directly

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
    String str = "DOC_87654321 -ABC76543- 959565412";
    String finalStr = "";
    String[] split = str.split("-");
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        finalStr +=
                split[i]
                        .replaceAll("([0-9])", "$1 ")
                        .trim()
                        + (i != split.length - 1 ? '-' : "");
    }
    System.out.println("finalStr = " + finalStr);
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic used inside the for loop?

Comment: @Noufal 1- split input string by `-` 2- replace digit of every parts with founded group ($1)  + space. 3- remove extra space from end of string (because of final digit).

Answer (score 1):

In case if you don't wanna use `Character.isDigit()` you can compare their ascii decimal values and use it like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "DOC_87654321 -ABC76543";
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
            if(str.charAt(i) >= 48 && str.charAt(i) <=57) {
                string.append(str.charAt(i)+" ");
            }else {
                string.append(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(string.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it also works

Comment: @Noufal If you are a beginner you should not directly use all the Java APIs